# Can SSMS Object Explorer Details configurations be exported?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, configuration

A number of employees make use of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). I have a configuration file for all new users for Environment (etc) configurations.

I want to deliver a uniform view for each database object type (tables, stored procedures, security, etc.).

I'm looking for a method to export an Object Explorer Details configuration or a program to configure the Object Explorer Details using a secondary source (text file, database).

I've provided an illustration of two Object Explorer Details configurations.

Object Explorer Details: View 1 (for Tables and Stored Procedures)
[image]

Object Explorer Details: View 2 (for Tables and Stored Procedures)
[image]

In advance, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. These settings are stored along with a bunch of other UI configuration in a binary file in your user profile directory.